# How to use Qooxdoo's Stores to request an ajax response with a POST?

Tags: ajax, json, store, qooxdoo

In the tutorial [enter link description here](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/1.6.x/pages/tutorials/tutorial-part-3.html) they only show this:

```
var url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json";
this.__store = new qx.data.store.Jsonp(url, null, "callback");
```

But I would need to communicate with my own server, so I've made some changes: (url and Jsonp to Json)

```
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/";
this.__store = new qx.data.store.Json(url);
```

But I would need to be able to send some information to the server when the store make the request like:

```
{serviceToUseOnServer: 'articles', argument1: 'xxx'}
```

This is like a POST request, but I don't really know how to send that data to the server using qooxdoo's Store models. Please don't tell me to use GET and encode all that data in an url.

Comment: Cross-post from the qooxdoo mailing list: http://qooxdoo.678.n2.nabble.com/How-to-use-Qooxdoo-s-Stores-to-request-an-ajax-response-with-a-POST-td7312461.html

Comment: thanks I will test soon, please put here as an answer to accept if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the possibility to configure the request object used to send the data. Just add a delegate to the store and implement the configureRequest method [1].

[1] http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.data.store.IStoreDelegate~configureRequest